# Сервис/нейросеть, которая делает короткое текстовое содержание видео с Ютуб по ссылке

Tags: искусственный-интеллект, chatgpt

Сервис/нейросеть, которая делает короткое текстовое содержание видео с Ютуб по ссылке напрямую. Т.е нужно просто выставить в строку ссылку, никаких танцев с чатгпт там не требовалось. Подскажите название

Comment: [тык](https://dzen.ru/a/ZMLoJW46M3PsuJ5M)